# Почему возникает ошибка java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, массивы

Данный код делает следующее:

- заполняет два массива случайными значениями от 1 до 40
- заполняет 3-ий массив суммами значений соответствующих индексов 1-го и 2-го массивов
- вычисляет среднее арифметическое 3-его массива и распечатывает его минимальное и максимальное значение.

При выполнении кода появляется ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 40
>        at massives.Massives.main(Massives.java:37)
>   Java Result: 1

Сам код:

```
import java.util.Random; //импорт необходимой статической библиотеки
public class Massives {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, p, m, s, d, g, c, k, max, min; 
        Random random1 = new Random(1);
        Random random2 = new Random(1);
        int[] array1 = new int[40]; 
        int[] array2 = new int[40];
        int[] array3 = new int[40];
            d = 0;                        
            for(i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) 
                array1[i] = random1.nextInt(40);
            for(p = 0; p < array2.length; p++) 
                array2[i] = random1.nextInt(40);
            for(m = 0; m < array3.length; m++)
                array3[m] = array1[m] + array2[m];
            for(s = 0; s < array3.length; s++)
                d += array3[s];
            g = d / array3.length;
            max = 0;
            for(c = 0; c < array3.length; c++)
                if(array3[i] > max) 
                    max = array3[i];
            min = array3[39]; 
            for(k = 39; k > 0; k--)
                min = array3[k];
            System.out.println(max);
            System.out.println(min);
            System.out.println(g);


        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

Comment: Оригинально конечно `for(p = 0; i < array2.length; p++) 
            array2[i] = random1.nextInt(40);`  вы уж определитесь, тут использовать `p` или `i` :)

Comment: ужс. Не надо объявлять счетчик цикла за пределами цикла без особой необходимости. Пишите `for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) ...`. В этом случае вы не сможете по ошибке использовать счетчик вне цикла и сможете повторно использовать имя переменной в других циклах (меньше переменных - проще читать).

Comment: И вообще, уберите лишние переменные. совершенно не обязательно в каждом цикле использовать свой счетчик. цикл закончился, `i` не нужна, значит ее можно уже в следующем цикле использовать. И опечаток на порядок меньше будет

Answer (score 3):

```
for(k = 39; c < array3.length; k--)
            min = array3[k];
```

У вас ошибка в условии цикла, поменяй `с` на `k`.

Comment: да у него как минимум в 3х циклах такое

Comment: я сразу обратил внимание на строку, указанную в ошибке)

Answer (score 3):

Внимательнее относитесь к работе с циклами.

```
public class Massives {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, p, m, s, d, g, c, k, max, min; 
    Random random1 = new Random(1);
    Random random2 = new Random(1);
    int[] array1 = new int[40]; 
    int[] array2 = new int[40];
    int[] array3 = new int[40];
        d = 0;                        
        for(i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) 
            array1[i] = random1.nextInt(40);
        for(p = 0; p < array2.length; p++) 
            array2[p] = random1.nextInt(40);
        for(m = 0; m < array3.length; m++)
            array3[m] = array1[m] + array2[m];
        for(s = 0; s < array3.length; s++)
            d += array3[s];
        g = d / array3.length;
        max = 0;
        for(c = 0; c < array3.length; c++)
            if(array3[c] > max) 
                max = array3[c];
        min = array3[39]; 
        for(k = 39; k < array3.length; k--)
            min = array3[k];
        System.out.println(max);
        System.out.println(min);
        System.out.println(g);


    // TODO code application logic here
    }
}
```